# Adding custom js to specific prestashop page

Tags: javascript, php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-modules

I'm using Prestashop v1.6.

When I navigate to this url route :

```
localhost/dumb/url
```

I want to add this script

```
src="localhost/dumb/url/script.js",
```

I need to expose that script only on that URL.

What I want: a few step by step guide to get idea of what should I do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard way:

Your URL (localhost/dumb/url) must have a controller created by your module. you can add your js file using this controller

```
$this->addJs(__PS_BASE_URI__.'/dumb/url/script.js');
```

Not recommended way:

Add this code to FrontController.php (or override this controller):

```
if (pathinfo($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])['dirname'] == '/dumb/url') {
    $this->addJs(__PS_BASE_URI__.'/dumb/url/script.js');
}
```

Comment: And instead of creating a module what is the other way , I try to add it directly inside public js , and it work but the thing is: the file is loaded everywhere , And now when i need my url to be loaded inside an iframe it doesn't work because my code check the "window.location.href" not the inside iframe

Comment: How you created this path(:localhost/dumb/url ) ?

Comment: They just give this url , I've no access to the back-office only FTP credentials

Comment: go for not recommend way